# Date in Upper Righthand Corner Causes Header to De-center

Tags: html, css

The date in the righthand corner of each post is causing the H2 Element to not be centered.

It's a very simple issue, with an annoying result. I've tried many things, and I still can't seem to stop it from de-centering! I know there's a fix, but I still cannot seem to fix it.

Here's an image describing the issue:

[image: Simple issue, annoying result...]

Here's the code:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    width: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.post {
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
}
.post p,h2 { 
    margin: 0;
}
.post h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
.post p {
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 40px;
    line-height: 1.8;
}
hr {visibility: hidden;} 
.date {
    float: right;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .container {width: 100%;}
    .post p {text-align: justify;text-indent: 0px;font-size: 14pt;}
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Henry's Blog!</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="post" id="10">
    <span class="date">10/15/17</span>
    <h2>Tenth Post</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Feugiat in ante metus dictum. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc.</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="post" id="9">
    <span class="date">10/15/17</span>
    <h2>Ninth Post</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Feugiat in ante metus dictum. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc.</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="post" id="8">
    <span class="date">10/15/17</span>
    <h2>Eighth Post</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Feugiat in ante metus dictum. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc.</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="post" id="7">
    <span class="date">10/15/17</span>
    <h2>Seventh Post</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Feugiat in ante metus dictum. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc.</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="post" id="6">
    <span class="date">10/15/17</span>
    <h2>Sixth Post</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Feugiat in ante metus dictum. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc.</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="post" id="5">
    <span class="date">10/15/17</span>
    <h2>Fifth Post</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Feugiat in ante metus dictum. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc.</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="post" id="4">
    <span class="date">10/15/17</span>
    <h2>Fourth Post</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Feugiat in ante metus dictum. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc.</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="post" id="3">
    <span class="date">10/15/17</span>
    <h2>Third Post</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Feugiat in ante metus dictum. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc.</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="post" id="2">
    <span class="date">10/15/17</span>
    <h2>Second Post</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Feugiat in ante metus dictum. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc.</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="post" id="1">
    <h2>First Post</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Feugiat in ante metus dictum. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc.</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <p>Blog Posts: <a href="#1">1</a> <a href="#2">2</a> <a href="#3">3</a> <a href="#4">4</a> <a href="#5">5</a> <a href="#6">6</a> <a href="#7">7</a> <a href="#8">8</a> <a href="#9">9</a> <a href="#10">10</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a padding to the `.post`, and that pushed everything inside it. I've added a `15px` padding, but feel free to change it. A margin will seperate your element from another one, so I've added a `0` margin to the `h2`s inside `.post`s.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.post {
  text-align: left;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.post h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Henry's Blog</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to Henry's Blog!</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="post" id="2">
        <h2>2nd Post</h2>
        <p>it works</p>
      </div>
      <div class="post" id="1">
        <h2>First Post</h2>
        <p>Welcome to my blog!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this with `Margin` or `Padding`tag.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.post {
  text-align: left;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

h1,
h2,
p {
  margin: 1px;
}

.title {
  margin-bottom: 15px
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 class="title">Welcome to Henry's Blog!</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="post" id="2">
      <h2>2nd Post</h2>
      <p>it works</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post" id="1">
      <h2>First Post</h2>
      <p>Welcome to my blog!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the margin of the elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Henry's Blog</title>
<style>
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.post {
  text-align: left;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}
/*New Code*/
h2{
  margin-top:0px;
}
p{
  margin-left:5px;
}
.post{
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Henry's Blog!</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="post" id="2">
    <h2>2nd Post</h2>
    <p>it works</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post" id="1">
    <h2>First Post</h2>
    <p>Welcome to my blog!</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a negative margin on the .container class (above '2nd Post')

```
.container{
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

To add a left margin for 'it works', try

```
// targets <p> elements inside any tag with class '.post'
.post p{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

To fix the lack of space between posts, you can add a top/bottom margin

```
.post{
    margin: 20px 0; // 1st value is for top & bottom (20px), 2nd value is for left & right (0px in this case)
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a margin to the entire container class using the same method. Up to you!

Answer (score 0):

u need to edit your css. just add this code:  [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/8cp90fyo/1/)

```
.post {
  text-align: left;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
h1, h2, p{
  margin: 1px;
}
```